# Cannot get Ajax CORS request in jquery to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I have had this exact code working a week ago and suddenly it stopped working.  I don't think anything has changed in bing's api, I have checked my account and still have plenty of searches left.  I even mimic this exact request in fiddler and it works.  Here is my code:

```
function queryBing(query, start, callback) {
            var requestStr = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query=%27" + query + "%27&$top=50&$format=json&ImageFilters=%27Size%3aMedium%27&Adult=%27Moderate%27";
            console.log(requestStr);
            console.log(accountKeyEncoded);
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: requestStr,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + accountKeyEncoded);
                },
                context: this,
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'GET',
                error: function(e){
                    e.Message;
                },
                success: callback
            });
        }
```

And its returning the following error:

```
OPTIONS https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query=%27te…$top=50&$format=json&ImageFilters=%27Size%3aMedium%27&Adult=%27Moderate%27 Origin http://localhost:81 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery.js:8706
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query=%27te…$top=50&$format=json&ImageFilters=%27Size%3aMedium%27&Adult=%27Moderate%27. Origin http://localhost:81 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have been able to query from my local computer and my website a week ago.  I tried looking inside my account settings and i cant find anywhere in Bing where I would ADD my domain.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? also, `$.support.cors = true` isn't needed. it's already true, if your browser supports cors. If your browser doesn't support cors, then setting it to true won't make it magically support it.

Comment: @KevinB Im testing in chrome, I tried firefox also, no luck

Comment: Are you sure you weren't using `jsonp` previously?

Comment: @JasonP, yes im 100% sure, I havent changed this code in so long, and its been working the whole time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem starting two days ago - as far as I can tell, Microsoft turned off CORS support in their Bing image search responses during the day on November 4. They no longer return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header of "*". I googled but couldn't find any information from Microsoft about this change. I worked around the problem by moving the http requests to my server.

Comment: Yes, we have been seeing this now for two days. We witnessed the same failure a month or so ago but only for about an hour. This cannot possibly be an intentional change. It's a catastrophic failure for any app that makes calls directly from the browser. We too have implemented this sub-optimal workaround, which we formerly reserved for very old browsers.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing happening in my web app. Maybe jsonp callbacks will suffice if the Bing API supports it.

Comment: I don't think jsonp works with basic authentication, which is needed by Bing.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Marketplace team has just rolled out a fix to this issue. OPTIONS requests should now again be correctly enabling Ajax CORS requests. If anyone has code which worked before November but is still broken please let us know on this thread so we can help resolve the issue!